# what is wrong with those codes? (Objective - c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

the / is fine but the % just dose not work.  I don't know why...

Comment: add your code...

Comment: I am not the best at explaining but if you either convert `Dseconds` into int - if you can afford the loss of decimals or `seconds` and `minutes` into double it'll work, my understanding is that due to `seconds` being declared an int but the RHS have a Double operated against a value, therefore confusing the compiler to be unable to find a suitable match to the data type of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% is for `int` or `long` data types, not `float` or `double`.

You can use `fmod()` or `fmodf()` from `<math.h>` to do the same operation.

To use fmod do this -

- `#include <math.h>` as the first step
- `fmod(Dseconds,60)` // do this to calculate your mod

Answer (score 1):

double can not be used as a Dividend to get a remainder

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
double Dseconds = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
int second = ((int)Dseconds % 60);
int minutes = ((int)Dseconds / 60) % 60;
NSTimeInterval hours = Dseconds / 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

你的Dseconds时double类型的，double跟int不能求余。